# What can I do/What is the best practice when frame content is larger than frame size?

Tags: beamer

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\logo{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Equation}
  \begin{exampleblock}{}
   \[
     \min_{\mu_{i},c_{i},w_{ij},\mathcal{A}}\quad \sum_{i}^{N}\varphi_{i}(\mu_{i}) + \lvert\mathcal{A}\rvert P_{f} + \frac{1}{\eta}\sum_{i = 1}^{N}\sum_{j\in{A}}w_{ij}^{H}w_{ij}
   \]
  \end{exampleblock}
  subject to
  \begin{exampleblock}{}
    \[
      \frac{1}{\mu_{i}- \lambda_{i}} + \frac{1}{c_{i} - \lambda_{i}}\leq\tau_{i}
    \]
    \[
      \lambda_{i} < \mu_{i},\lambda_{i}<c_{i}
  %    4545
  \]
  \[
    c_i{i} \leq B_{i}\log(1+\text{SINR}_{i}(\mathcal{A}))
  \]
  \[
    \sum_{i=1}^{N}w_{ij}^{H}w_{ij}\leq E_{i},\quad \forall i\in \mathcal{N}, \quad \forall j\in \mathcal{L}
  \]
  \end{exampleblock}
  \begin{itemize}
   %symbol's used in the equation meaning
    \item $\varphi_{i}(\mu_{i})$\quad VM $i$'s power consumption
    \item $\mu_{i}$\qquad VM $i$'s computation capacity/service rate/processing rate
    \item $P_{f}$\qquad power consumption active fibre links
    \item $\eta\in(0,1)$\quad ineffficiency coefficient amplifier in RRH
    \item $\mathcal{A}$\qquad set of active RRHs
    \item $w_{ij}\in\mathbb{C}^{k}$\quad transmit beamformer for UE $i$ from RRH $j$
    \item $i\in\mathcal{N}$
    \item $j\in\mathcal{A}$
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that really is up to you and your intended audience  you could use a smaller font (but does the back row of the audience want to read that much mathematics in a small font?) or you could say less, or you could use two slides.  Note that you should never have one `\[\]` environment straight after another, use a multi-line environment such as `gather*` (or you could drop the list of symbols, which might be more information than needed in a slide)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `gather*` takes more space. https://pasteboard.co/H8xxy8Q.png

Comment: Or use two columns and put the second equation in the first column and the list of variables in the second column.  Columns can have different widths.  You can also add `[shrink=n]` for some value of *n* to shrink the slide (but with @DavidCarlisle's caveat.)

Comment: it is unlikley that a single gather takes more space than four `\[\]` ???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you can test the code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pWzxrcVSDQ/

Comment: or split frame to more slides ...

Comment: you had a spurious `\\ ` after the last row, making a blank line

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed the `\\` of last equation. Nevertheless `gather*` takes more space, but less then having `\\`.  You can see the output https://pasteboard.co/H8ASBSz.png and code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zvwWW3JHS7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of wasted space in your slide with centred math taking up the whole width of the slide. I would put the math in one column and the variable list in another column and reduce just the size of the variable list.

With just the columns code, there's some extra vertical space both at the top of the slide and in the first block.  I'm not sure where this is coming from. I've added some manual negative space so that the  lefthand logo is not covered.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\logo{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Equation}
\vspace*{-2.5\baselineskip}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.62\linewidth}
  \begin{exampleblock}{}%
   \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\[
     \min_{\mu_{i},c_{i},w_{ij},\mathcal{A}}\quad \sum_{i}^{N}\varphi_{i}(\mu_{i}) + \lvert\mathcal{A}\rvert P_{f} + \frac{1}{\eta}\sum_{i = 1}^{N}\sum_{j\in{A}}w_{ij}^{H}w_{ij}
   \]
  \end{exampleblock}
  subject to
  \begin{exampleblock}{}%
    \[
      \frac{1}{\mu_{i}- \lambda_{i}} + \frac{1}{c_{i} - \lambda_{i}}\leq\tau_{i}
    \]
    \[
      \lambda_{i} < \mu_{i},\lambda_{i}<c_{i}
  %    4545
  \]
  \[
    c_i{i} \leq B_{i}\log(1+\text{SINR}_{i}(\mathcal{A}))
  \]
  \[
    \sum_{i=1}^{N}w_{ij}^{H}w_{ij}\leq E_{i},\quad \forall i\in \mathcal{N}, \quad \forall j\in \mathcal{L}
  \]
  \end{exampleblock}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.38\linewidth}
\footnotesize\raggedright
  \begin{itemize}
   %symbol's used in the equation meaning
    \item $\varphi_{i}(\mu_{i})$\quad VM $i$'s power consumption
    \item $\mu_{i}$\qquad VM $i$'s computation capacity/service rate/processing rate
    \item $P_{f}$\qquad power consumption active fibre links
    \item $\eta\in(0,1)$\quad ineffficiency coefficient amplifier in RRH
    \item $\mathcal{A}$\qquad set of active RRHs
    \item $w_{ij}\in\mathbb{C}^{k}$\quad transmit beamformer for UE $i$ from RRH $j$
    \item $i\in\mathcal{N}$
    \item $j\in\mathcal{A}$
  \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Don't we set column height as well as width to show the leftside logo?

Comment: @alhelal No, you can't set the column height.

Comment: There also some space top of the first block.

Comment: @alhelal I've added a manual hack for the spacing. I'm not sure where the extra space is coming from.

Comment: yes, now the output is good. Thank you for your effort.